# Where to start researching on video recognition

Tags: opencv

Sometime in the middle future I want to start growing my home automation system to have video capabilities. I've started doing some research on this, and I'm patient and a fast learner, but it's a very dense field and much more mathematically intense than I'm used to. I've never done anything with video programmatically, and while I've read over the docs for OpenCV and some really intense stuff like the research papers [here](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/eval/#references), a depressing amount of it is gibberish to me. I do have a background in multi-variable Calculus and Linear Algebra, but that was a long time ago. Right now I do almost all my programming in Java, with a growing amount of C#. I'm also taking a course in Machine Learning, which I think will help with object classification.

What's the ground level here? What kind of math do I need to study, what kind of Hello World apps should I write, what kind of cameras do I need? What is the language of choice for this kind of work? What is and is not actually possible with the state of the art right now?

### Objectives:

Here are some of the things I hope to some day accomplish with this:

To begin with, I would like most of the time to keep a short "buffer" history, and start recording to a local network location either when certain features are recognized or when certain events are raised by other parts of the system.

I would like to emulate Dropcam's ["Activity Zones"](https://www.dropcam.com/cloud-recording), where a user can define significant regions in a fixed camera's viewpoint and specify custom events to associate with mostion in those regions.

I would like to be able to recognize faces and compare against a small database of known trained examples to establish in real time, in conjunction with other occupancy sensors, who is in a room.

I would like to be able to use multiple cameras to track the location of objects in real time against a provided floor plan.

I've been playing around some with various microcontrollers, and I would like to do as much preprocessing as I can at the camera before the video feeds to my central server, in order to parallelize things as much as I can.

Comment: Another, easier question: Does anyone have any experience with the Nest API? How much of this could be substituted by buying Dropcams and routing them through my system?

Comment: example of features for "when certain features are recognized"? "track the location of objects" what kind of objects? I guess the easiest part will be the face recognition part since there exist solutions http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html but never tested it so no guarantee. maybe youll need different cameras for each task.

Comment: easiest way to implement "activity detection" is background subtraction. which will often fail for areas with naturally changing lighting conditions.

Comment: optical flow, video stabilization, human action recognition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my humble suggestions.

For background, it might help to familiarize yourself with the field of computer vision in general (since what you are doing falls within its classic domain). Helpful mathematical background include signal processing (i.e. Fourier transform theory) which is used often for recognition in robotics and for image processing in general, "mathematical programming" (convex optimization, linear/integer programming, etc...), and some probability theory / stochastic processes & matrix calculus (especially if you want to track with kalman filters or particle filters). However, knowing all this background is unnecessary if you just plan to use tools like OpenCV.

For literature, go to google scholar and type "motion tracking" or "video recognition", for example.

Honestly, for real-time, I do not think C++ has much competition. You have already looked at OpenCV, but look at Boost too. Matlab also has some fast and amazing toolboxes, but less flexbility obviously. And expensive. I have heard good things about the latest mathematica for computer vision too, but that has similar problems to matlab.

However, since you are just starting in the field, my suggestion is to start with Python. The numpy, scipy, scikit-learn combo is awesome, and it has opencv bindings. Also check out PyStruct for structured learning, which is really nice for this kind of thing ,and Theano for deep learning. These tools are slow but almost ridiculously easy to use; great for prototyping.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the things that you would like to do falls in computer vision, it is better to learn the state of the art technologies. As of now, it is deep learning(using which sota results in Video activity recognition, object detection and tracking, et al are obtained).

For the mathematical background to learn Deep learning, you require linear algebra, probability and statistics, multivariate calculus and some optimisation techniques.You can start reading [this book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/). It assumes the least background.

In the programming side, it is enough to know python.

For a curated list of deep learning resources for computer vision, check [this website](https://github.com/kjw0612/awesome-deep-vision). It contains information about video analysis too.